# Error 404 al hacer scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

estoy realizando un scraping web con python y selenium, la página web abre con normalidad si la busco en el navegador, pero cuando lo hago desde el script me arroja error 404

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

website = 'pagina_web/data/recordings'
path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
time.sleep(10)
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(10)
```

Por temas de seguridad tengo que ocultar el link de la página web, el link es protocolo http y no https

Comment: Significa que ese recurso no existe. Posiblemente hay una redirección por Javascript.

Comment: @Alfabravo Como se puede hacer que cargue el redireccionamiento por JS